# Automatically generate Created date in Fluent NHibernate Automapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I am using Fluent NHibernate's automapping / conventions functionality to map my entities to database tables. I have this abstract class which every domain entity in my application derives itself from:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

How can I modify my Fluent configuration so that the `Created` property has it's value automatically set to the value of `DateTime.Now` when the record is saved in the database.

Here is my Fluent configuration for reference:

```
private FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration GetConfiguration()
{

    return Fluently
        .Configure()
        .Database(() =>
            {
                return MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("main"));
            }                                     
        )
        .Mappings(
            x =>
            {
                var persistenceModel = new PersistenceModel() { ValidationEnabled = false };
                x.UsePersistenceModel(persistenceModel)
                 .AutoMappings.Add(
                    AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>().Where(Exceptions.Load)
                    .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never())
                    .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultCascade.SaveUpdate())
                    .Conventions.Add(new FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.Builders.JoinConventionBuilder().Always(a => a.Fetch.Join()))
                );
            }
        )
        .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use NHibernate’s event listeners for this;

```
public class AuditEventListener : IPreUpdateEventListener, IPreInsertEventListener
{
    public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent @event)
    {
        var audit = @event.Entity as IHaveAuditInformation;
        if (audit == null)
            return false;

        var time = DateTime.Now;
        var name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UpdatedAt", time);
        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UpdatedBy", name);

        audit.UpdatedAt = time;
        audit.UpdatedBy = name;

        return false;
    }

    public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent @event)
    {
        var audit = @event.Entity as IHaveAuditInformation;
        if (audit == null)
            return false;


        var time = DateTime.Now;
        var name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "CreatedAt", time);
        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UpdatedAt", time);
        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "CreatedBy", name);
        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UpdatedBy", name);

        audit.CreatedAt = time;
        audit.CreatedBy = name;
        audit.UpdatedAt = time;
        audit.UpdatedBy = name;

        return false;
    }

    private void Set(IEntityPersister persister, object[] state, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        var index = Array.IndexOf(persister.PropertyNames, propertyName);
        if (index == -1)
            return;
        state[index] = value;
    }
}
```

https://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener